# Can I use client certificates for authentication in WCF without requiring accounts in either AD or Windows?

Tags: wcf-security

I'd like to use client certificates to authenticate callers to my WCF service (hosted in IIS).

I don't want to use either of the built-in solutions (Client Certificate Mapping or IIS Client Certificate Mapping), because they require additional administrative overhead (local user accounts or AD accounts). That is: adding another account requires raising a change request with the IT department and then waiting for three weeks.

Is there any way that I can configure IIS/WCF to accept client certificates and to map them to user accounts defined by something like an ASP.NET MembershipProvider?

I want to use one of the HTTP bindings. That is: basicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding or webHttpBinding.

Comment: Are you using transport-level security or message-level security?